# How can I check reaslon of crashing app in appconnect dashboard?

Tags: ios, swift

From time to time some users send me movie with crashing application. How can I check reason of crashing in appstoreconnect?  In dashboard I see only crash statistic. Where should I looking for ?

Google Console for android has crash stack but apple..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used XCode to upload your app to the store, I suggest you open XCode, then go to Window menu and choose "Organizer". Select your app and, on the left, choose "Crashes".